# Why isn't the usb_driver working...?

Tags: android, android-studio, driver

I have just started android programming, and after watching many tutorials and reading many articles I learned that if I want to run my programs on my android phone, I will need to install the usb_driver. I have done that, but when I go to device manager, in other devices, my phone has a yellow exclamation error. This is normal, but it should go away after **right click->update driver software->browse->C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\extras\google\usb_driver->next**. But, after doing this, I get the error:
[image]

Without downloading the usb_driver, my device just wouldn't get detected. I have already allowed usb debugging, and allow mock locations, so right now I just need the driver. I have read almost all the other articles and tutorials, but my device still doesn't show up?

Comment: Unfortunately many devices needs their own driver on windows, and won't work well with the generic google one. What kind of device do you have? You might want to check on the manufacturer's website for a specific driver.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out that besides for installing the updates for the computer, I must also go into my computer and allow permission **for** these updates to run. After that, I followed [these](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G9Xsg7DkqN4) instructions.

Answer (score 2):

There is also a great tool: [adb driver installer](http://adbdriver.com/), that allows you to install drivers for almost any phone, without need for the 'software suites' that often come along drivers.